# Why does this Ruby code fail to write to the log file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, logging, daemon

Once the script is daemonized then the logger can't write to the file anymore. So how and when should I initialise the log?

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'daemons'
require 'logging'

def create_new_logger
    logger = Logging.logger['trend-analyzer']
    logger.add_appenders(
        Logging.appenders.rolling_file('./logs/trend-analyzer.log'),
        Logging.appenders.stdout
    )
    logger.level = :debug
    return logger
end

logger = create_new_logger

#this log message gets written to the log file
logger.debug Time.new 

Daemons.run_proc('ForestPress', :log_dir => '.logs', :backtrace => true) do
    running_as_daemon = true

    #this log message does NOT get written to the log file
    logger.debug Time.new

    loop do
        #this log message does NOT get written to the log file
        logger.info Time.new    
        sleep 5 
    end
end
```

---

**EDIT**

I notice the current path changes from where I executed the script to `/`. Could this be why I can't log messages?

---

**EDIT 2**

I now save the original path before becoming a daemon and then use `Dir.chdir` to set the path to the original path. I can then open the file directly and write to it. However the logging gem can't write to it still.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how it started working

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'daemons'
require 'logging'

def create_new_logger
    logger = Logging.logger['trend-analyzer']
    logger.add_appenders(
        Logging.appenders.rolling_file('./logs/trend-analyzer.log'),
        Logging.appenders.stdout
    )
    logger.level = :debug
    return logger
end

current_dir = Dir.pwd

Daemons.run_proc('ForestPress', :log_dir => '.logs', :backtrace => true) do
    Dir.chdir(current_dir)  

    logger = create_new_logger

    loop do
        puts Dir.pwd
        logger.debug Time.new   
        sleep 5 
    end
end
```