# "log writing failed. closed stream" in Ruby Daemon interacting with a DB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, daemon

I've created a daemon.
Both on real server and development win7 laptop it outputs

> log writing failed. closed stream

The point is that on win7 it works: taking hashtag record from the DB and than placing results too.
But according to logs on Debian it only gets hashtag record from the DB.

Code:

```
require File.expand_path('../../config/environment',  __FILE__)
require 'rubygems'
tag = HashTag.first

TweetStream::Daemon.new('tracker').track('#'+tag.tag) do |status|
  unless status.media.blank?
    puts status.media.first.media_url
    tag.images.create(
        provider_id: 2,
        when_published: Time.now,
        url: status.media.first.media_url,
        author_id: status.from_user,
        post_id: status.id
    )
  end

end
```

It would be really great is somebody give me a hint what i'm doing wrong.

Comment: If you called `create!` you would get an exception if there was an error inserting. This could be returning `false` and you would have no idea. It also might not be called in the first place. Do you see the output of the `puts` statement inside the Daemon block?

Comment: yup, image urls appears in console, however, after each img url 10-15 exceptions about log writing fails appears

Comment: Is this relevant?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10749404/why-does-this-ruby-code-fail-to-write-to-the-log-file

Comment: I'm seeing this same error on Ubuntu Upstart script logs. I know this is old, but did you solved this?